# Is the "for + proposition" form still used nowadays?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

I am currently studying English and as such enjoy reading English books from time to time; for instance I have recently been reading the fifth book of *A Song of Ice and Fire* since the French version was not to be released anytime soon.

As I read it I often came across a grammatical form I had never encountered previously, this form being the usage of "for" to introduce propositions as per this example:

*"We must learn english, for it is one of the most widely-spoken language."*

My question if the following: is this form correct (I do think it is), and if it is then is it still used today? I really like this usage of the "for" preposition but still, I'd like to be sure it can be used before actually using it (in class or elsewhere).

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** Upon further searches, now knowing that "for" is in that case a conjunction, I found out that this form is perfectly correct - though it is more of a literary form.

Comment: The *for* in that sentence is a conjunction. See [this dictionary entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for#for__19) for more information.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Then it seems it can be used, according to your link? Thanks for you comment!

Comment: As Matt says, this can be found in any dictionary, but as a courtesy I am closing this as a duplicate instead.

Comment: I apologize, I had made searches prior to posting but it proved somewhat hard to find something relevant to my question (and not all dictionnaries give this precise usage of _for_). Thanks for your input!

Comment: I don't see any relation between the essence of this question and the purported 'original post' or the dictionary reference. This can very well have its own answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: What rather helped me was Matt's comment, since the dictionnary page mentioned that _for_ used as a conjunction was a literary usage; later by googling "for as a conjunction" (I did not know it was one before) I again found out it is not a common usage (and that it is only found in books).